# rhive.connect error: cannot modify RHIVE_UDF_DIR

Tags: r, hive

I am trying to connect to Hive from R with the latest RHive package in HDP 2.4. The installation seemed to have gone smoothly, since I was able to call the library of RHive. When I execute

```
rhive.connect(host="192.168.56.101",port=10000, hiveServer2=TRUE)
```

I got this error message:

> Cannot modify mapred.child.env at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime.

After some googling around, I added the following to the /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml file:

```
<property>
      <name>hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append</name>
      <value>mapred.child.env</value>
</property>
```

After restarting hive-server2, the original error message is now replaced by this one:

> Cannot modify RHIVE_UDF_DIR at runtime. It is not in list of params
>   that are allowed to be modified at runtime.

I tried adding RHIVE_UDF_DIR right next to map.child.env, like this:

```
 <property>
  <name>hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append</name>
  <value>mapred.child.env,RHIVE_UDF_DIR</value>
 </property>
```

But this did not resolve the problem; it brought back the original error message that I was getting at the very beginning. Any thoughts on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late reply but I just came across this thread. Using java regex instead of comma separated would work. This worked for me this morning.

Config parameter should be added under hive-site.xml

```
hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append=mapred\.child\.env|RHIVE_UDF_DIR
```

Ps: Backslash was not displaying above so adding screenshot link.
[config parameter with proper java regex for values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwEGH.png)